# Swift complains of undeclared type, but that doesn't seem to be the problem

Tags: arrays, swift, fetch, typeerror

I am trying to fetch records in Core Data.

```
func fetchOrg() {
     var **internalOrganization** = [InternalOrganizationMO]() //NSManagedClass
     let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "InternalOrganization")
     fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
     do {
          let result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as **internalOrganization**  **////Compiler flags Error here**
     } catch {
          fatalError("Failed to fetch internal organization \(error)")
     }
 }
```

`InternalOrganizationMO` is a `ManagedObject` Class corresponding to the object model and it seems clear to me that `internalOrganization` is declared to be an array of those objects, so the flagged error seems to be off.  My understanding is that this is the kind of object that is supposed to be the target of a fetch, but I am definitely on the learning curve here.

Is it that the fetch needs to be targeted at a *Type* instead of an *array*--thus, the complaint about my not providing a named type? If that is it, am I simply supposed to provide the `ManagedObject`? If that is so, how on earth do I determine how many records are returned?

Is this really better than just using the interface to SQLite?
Thanks, sorry for the rant.

Answer (score 0):

You typecast objects as types, not objects as objects.

Example:

```
let a = b as! [String]
```

**and not**:

```
let a = [String]()
let c = b as! a
```

---

### Solution #1:

Change `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` to specify the type to be explicitly `InternalOrganizationMO`, like so:

```
NSFetchRequestResult<InternalOrganizationMO>
```

This `fetchRequest` has now the proper associated type `InternalOrganizationMO` and will be used accordingly to return objects of this type.
You then won't need to typecast `result` again and the following code should work just fine:

```
func fetchOrg() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<InternalOrganizationMO>(entityName: "InternalOrganization")

    do {
        let internalOrganization = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        /*
         internalOrganization will be of type [InternalOrganizationMO]
         as that is the return type of the fetch now.
         */

        //handle internalOrganization here (within the do block)

        print(internalOrganization.count)
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch internal organization \(error)")
    }
}
```

---

### Solution #2:

If you want this method to work even if the `fetchRequest` try or typecasting fails then you can do this:

```
func fetchOrg() {
    var internalOrganization = [InternalOrganizationMO]()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "InternalOrganization")

    do {
        internalOrganization = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [InternalOrganizationMO]
        /*
         You ofcourse wouldn't want the above optional binding to fail but even if it
         does, atleast your method can stay consistent and continue with an empty array
         */
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch internal organization \(error)")
    }

    //handle internalOrganization here
    print(internalOrganization.count)
}
```

---

The choice of solution, depends on your design and requirements.